# ¿Cómo oculto la barra de estado en Swift2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Cómo pueden ver el contenido en mi aplicación se traslapa a la barra de contenido. Yo no quiero que mi aplicación sea así. ¿Cómo puedo quitar la barra de contenidos y hacer mi aplicación; pantalla completa?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementa el siguiente método en tu controlador:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Si lo que quieres es ocultarla para toda la aplicación, tienes que ir a tu info.plist y asignar un valor a la key con nombre `View controller-based status bar appearance` y darle el valor `NO`, y también añadir la nueva key `Status bar is initially hidden` y ponerla a `YES`.

Comment: muchas gracias la función lo oculto.

Comment: me alegro de que te haya funcionado